# Deleted job in maintenance plan in sql 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I restore a deleted job in maintenance plan on SQL 2008 R2. Or is there a file location where in I can copy the script injected in the maintenance plan..

Answer (score 0):

### Did you backed up the jobs?

this is one reason why we script all our jobs on a weekly basis Whistling

What you could do is : ( ON A test SERVER IF YOU CAN ! )

- shut down SQLAgent.
- make a new backup of msdb (to a new backup file !!!)
- restore the pervious msdb bacup
- activate the agent xp's 
  -- enable Agent XPs

  EXEC sp_configure 'Agent XPs','1'
    RECONFIGURE
- script your job
- restore the newly created msdb backup
- implement the job from the script in the pervious step
- start sqlagent

Actually , you can restore msdb like any other userdb e.g.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [msdb_rest] FROM DISK =
    N'X:\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\msdbFull.BAK' 
WITH FILE = 1
, MOVE N'MSDBData' TO N'X:\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\msdb_rest.mdf'
, MOVE N'MSDBLog' TO N'X:\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\msdb_rest_1.ldf'

GO
```

Keep in mind you are tampering with system stuff ! 
This is not advized !!

So you could pull over the data of the missing job this way

```
insert into msdb.dbo.sysjobs
SELECT *
from msdb_rest.dbo.sysjobs J
where J.name ='DBA_Db_Rebuild_Reindex'
go

insert into msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
Select JS.*
from msdb_rest.dbo.sysjobsteps JS
inner join msdb_rest.dbo.sysjobs J
on J.job_id = js.job_id
where J.name ='DBA_Db_Rebuild_Reindex'
go
```

With the above steps, you will have the job and its steps.

You will not yet have the schedule, ...

### Play it safe, start with a full backup

*i've read this from here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic749226-146-1.aspx*